# mu and mu4e can't find phrase query like \"foo bar baz\"

Tags: mu4e

Often when I do:

```
mu find \"foo bar baz\"
```

I get no results, but if I do:

```
mu find from:qux
```

The correct email appears, and its (HTML) body does indeed include "foo bar baz" (without quotes), which I can confirm by searching the buffer in mu4e, and I can see in the raw text version.

On emails smaller than roughly 100 KB, I do not have this problem.

What would cause this? Does mu and/or xapian refuse to index emails larger than a given size?

UPDATE:
`man mu index` shows this:

> E-mail messages which are not stored in something resembling a maildir leaf-directory (cur and new) are ignored, as are the cache directories for notmuch and gnus, and any dot-directory.

But I confirmed that my message is stored in a `cur` directory (`~/Maildir/me@foo.com/INBOX/cur/...`).

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the quotes here.

Comment: In mu4e, you don't need to escape the quotes, but in most shells, including bash, you do need the quotes, as specified here: https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/cheatsheet.html. But the problem here is that the behavior is the same, regardless of single quotes or double-backslashes.

Comment: Oh, you're right. You need to escape the quotes to treat the entire phrase as a search term, otherwise each word is treated as a separate term. I can't reproduce your problem though. Maybe the `embed:` argument would help?